# OpenCV OutputArray Heap corruption?

Tags: opencv, parameter-passing, heap-corruption

I'm coding a function that does some image processing with OpenCV 2.4.3 and I'm using InputArray and OutputArray as parameter types. In a Debug build using Visual Studio 2008 Express, the code bellow (minimal test case) gives me this very weird error after the first iteration of the for(;;) loop:

*"HEAP[Test.exe]: Heap block at 0032F598 modified at 0032F5D0 past requested size of 30 Windows has triggered a breakpoint in Test.exe.
This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in Test.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.
This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while Test.exe has focus."*

```
struct Corner
{
    float x;
    float y;
    float response;
};


void my_CornerDetector(InputArray _image, OutputArray _corners)
{
    vector<Corner> corners;
    Corner c;
    c.x = 150; c.y = 200; c.response = 0.1485;
    corners.push_back(c);
    corners.push_back(c);
    corners.push_back(c);
    Mat(corners).copyTo(_corners);
}

void main()
{
    Mat frame, frame_gray;    
    namedWindow("Output", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE ); 

    VideoCapture capture;
    capture.open(0);
    for (;;)
    {
        capture >> frame;
        if (frame.empty())
            break;

        cvtColor( frame, frame_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );

        vector<Corner> corners;
        my_CornerDetector( frame_gray, corners);

        for( int i = 0; i < corners.size(); i++ )
            circle( frame, Point2f(corners[i].x, corners[i].y), 4, CV_RGB(255,0,0), -1, 8, 0 ); 

        imshow("Output", frame);

        char key = (char)waitKey(2);
        switch (key)
        {
        case 27:
        case 'q':
          return;
          break;
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that corners had the right values (3 times the same corner) within the for loop during the first iteration and before the crash. If instead of using my Corner type for the std::vector I use a Point2f (and I forget about the response field) the example works as expected. And if instead of using a OutputArray I use std::vector &_corners it also works fine. What's going on?? I get the feeling maybe I need to register my type Corner somewhere so that it can work with OutputArray but I haven't seen such a thing in the OpenCV documentation.

BTW, I didn't press F12 ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies with passing in the Vector corners. It doesn't get cast to OutputArray.

Replace the block:

```
vector<Corner> corners;
my_CornerDetector( frame_gray, corners);    
for( int i = 0; i < corners.size(); i++ )
circle(frame, Point2f(corners[i].x, corners[i].y), 4, CV_RGB(255,0,0), -1, 8, 0 );
```

with:

```
Mat corners;
my_CornerDetector( frame_gray, corners);        
for( int i = 0; i < corners.rows; i++ )
{
  Corner c = corners.at<Corner>(i, 0);
  circle(frame, Point2f(c.x, c.y), 4, CV_RGB(255,0,0), -1, 8, 0 );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your alternative works. 
But I thought that the point of using OutputArray is that it can deal with either cv::Mat or std::vectors, that's how it's used in OpenCV modules, and in my case I want corners to be a std::vector. It works well if corners is a vector<Point2f>. So I don't understand the difference, I have added a default constructor and copy constructor to my Corner type and see if it makes any difference but it doesn't.

Comment: Hi. If you are interested in going deeper into the rabbit hole, you can take a look at matrix.cpp in OpenCV's source where the OutputArray s declared. Also, you can look at how OpenCV's functions such as split(...) which writes out to vector<>... works BUT I suspect that the OutputArray is somehow only intended to work with a restricted set of templated vectors i.e. vector<Mat>, vector<Point> etc. Let me say tt I'm not entire sure about this but this is the sense I get from taking a quick glance at the code. If I have the time I'll look into it further and let you know.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I've had a look at the InputArray/OutputArray definitions I can see they are templated with parameter _Tp. I haven't been able to see the complete picture but I suspect too that _Tp can be only one of the DataType traits, which are POD types and combinations of them in the form CV_<bit-depth>{U|S|F}C(<number_of_channels>) . So in my case I could use a Vec3f instead of my struct Corner and it would work well. Problem I guess if I wanted two ints and one float type??
It's not obvious from OpenCV documentation that you can't define you own types for this _Tp template parameter.

Comment: @martinako Yep the documentation is not very clear on this. In fact, I'm not even sure that users (other than the OpenCV developers) are intended to make use of InputArray and OutputArray in their code (although there have been several code examples online). I get this sense from this line in the docs: "... Normally, you should not care of those intermediate types (and you should not declare variables of those types explicitly) ...". Here is the link to this part of the doc: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/intro.html#inputarray-and-outputarray